# Can I use arcane slots to activate a page of spell knowledge provided I am also a divine caster?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

In a current campaign I am playing a sorcerer/oracle. If I have a [page of spell knowledge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/page-of-spell-knowledge/) with a divine spell on it, can I use my arcane slots to cast it?

The page's description says:

> If the bearer is a spontaneous spellcaster and has that spell on her class spell list, she may use her spell slots to cast that spell as if it were one of her spells known

Comment: Hi @ymmijx, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange! Check out our [tour] to see how we work here, and when you reach 20 rep, you can join us in [chat].

Answer (score 3):

## A [*page of spell knowledge*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/page-of-spell-knowledge/) essentially adds spells to the bearer's spells *known*, not to the bearer's spell *list*

The *page of spell knowledge* says, "If the bearer is a spontaneous spellcaster and has that spell on her class spell list, she may use her spell slots to cast that spell as if it were one of her spells known."

Thus, if the bearer of the *page* is a [sorcerer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/) and has that spell on her sorcerer spell list, she can use her sorcerer spell slots to cast that spell as if it were one of her sorcerer spells known. Likewise, if the bearer is an [oracle](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle) and has that spell on her oracle spell list, she can use her oracle spell slots to cast that spell as if it were one of her oracle spells know.

However, if the bearer of the *page* is a multiclass oracle/sorcerer and has that spell *either* only on her oracle spell list *or* only on her sorcerer spell list, she does *not* have the spell on that *other* spell list, and she's stuck casting the spell using the spell slots of whatever spellcasting class *does* have that spell on its spell list.

The *page of spell knowledge* doesn't *change* the sorcerer's spellcasting that says, "A sorcerer casts arcane spells drawn primarily from the sorcerer/wizard spell list," nor does the *page* change the oracle's spellcasting that says, "An oracle casts divine spells drawn from the cleric spell lists." If a spell's not on a class's list, that class's spell slots can't typically be used to cast it, even with the help of a *page of spell knowledge*.

Answer (score 0):

**Divine and Arcane classes doesn't naturally share their spell-slots**

As Hey I Can Chan's answer explains, Sorcerers and Oracles cast their spells from different spell lists and then prevent you to use the spell slots of one class for another.

However a way to solve this issue would be the [Mystic Theurge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/core-rulebook/mystic-theurge/) class, which  allows to share the spell slots for spontaneous-caster classes, as explained in [Paizo FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qx6) with an oracle/sorcerer/mystic theurge example:

> Likewise, an oracle/sorcerer/mystic theurge can use sorcerer spell slots to cast oracle spells, or oracle spell slots to cast sorcerer spells, so long as the level increases and level limits described in the combine spells ability are implemented. Neither class is affected by the "only spells they have prepared" rule because that rule only applies to mystic theurges who have levels in a non-spontaneous casting class.

Comment: Why would it apply here? Character in question is not a Mystic Theurge as far as we know.

Comment: Mystic Theurge in the example is a complement for a more generic situation, to show that  non-spontaneous caster classes doesn't share their spell slots the same way. However this example shows that in the case of a Sorcerer/Oracle only, the spell slot sharing works naturally.

Comment: The prestige class [mystic theurge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/core-rulebook/mystic-theurge/) has the specific class feature combined spells that allows its classes to… well… combine spells like this. Most other classes, however, don't have such a class feature.

Comment: No? This is an answer about "Combined Spells (Su)" ability. Why would spontaneous casters be able to combine spells without having Combined Spells ability? (edit: @HeyICanChan was 5 seconds faster than me)

Comment: Got it, I indeed went too fast on this one. I'll edit my answer accordingly, which gives a way to do the sharing slot, but the main answer remains a "no"